# Automatic Modal window?/ Welcoming popup box

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I was planning to add a welcome popup box that displays "WELCOME! (name of the user)" (welcome message) but I dont know how to make the modal window popup automatically after the user has logged in and was redirected to the home page. any suggestions? anything would help! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. You can redirect the user with a parameter added if it's his first login to the app, or have a specific welcome page where you redirect the first time the user logs in (You should save when the user did this first login)

*Note:* I would avoid a useless welcome message, and change it to an "onboarding" start instead.

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely Javascript then you should set a cookie when the user logged in successfully. On your home page you should read the cookie, if a flag is true (meaning user is logged in), pop up a window.

If you wrote your website with PHP, this is rather simple with SESSION variables as well.